# Failed to compile React Native Web

Tags: react-native

I am a beginner to react-native.

What I did :

1)expo init newProj

2)Selected empty project

3)expo start --web

4)Select Run at Android

==========Till Now Everything was working and compiling================

5)Select Run at web browser then getting this error:

```
WEB: Failed to compile
D:/ReactNative/newProj/node_modules/@unimodules/react-native-adapter/build/errors/CodedError.js
ReferenceError: D:\ReactNative\newProj\node_modules\@unimodules\react-native-adapter\build\errors\CodedError.js: Unknown helper createSuper
```

This is my App.js

```
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View } from 'react-native';

export default function App() {
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Text>Hello World! </Text>
    </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
});
```

This is my package.json

```
{
  "main": "node_modules/expo/AppEntry.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "expo start",
    "android": "expo start --android",
    "ios": "expo start --ios",
    "web": "expo start --web",
    "eject": "expo eject"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "expo": "~36.0.0",
    "react": "~16.9.0",
    "react-dom": "~16.9.0",
    "react-native": "https://github.com/expo/react-native/archive/sdk-36.0.0.tar.gz",
    "react-native-web": "~0.11.7"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-preset-expo": "~8.0.0",
    "@babel/core": "^7.0.0"
  },
  "private": true
}
```

This is my basel.config.js

```
module.exports = function(api) {
  api.cache(true);
  return {
    presets: ['babel-preset-expo'],
  };
};
```

This is CodeError.js

```
/**
 * A general error class that should be used for all errors in Expo modules.
 * Guarantees a `code` field that can be used to differentiate between different
 * types of errors without further subclassing Error.
 */
export class CodedError extends Error {
    constructor(code, message) {
        super(message);
        this.code = code;
    }
}
//# sourceMappingURL=CodedError.js.map
```

Answer (score 2):

In my project - not react-native at all - the same error started popping up yesterday. It seems to be related to babel-loader@8.1.0 which was just recently released.

In my case, it helped to pin its version to 8.0.6, the previous one.

If you are using yarn instead of npm, you should be able to get around it for now by adding a resolutions field to your package.json.

First of all, make sure you do have babel-loader in your project by running `yarn why babel-loader` - it should report something rather than nothing. If that's the case, this workaround should help:

In package.json, add:

```
"resolutions:" {
    "babel-loader": "8.0.6"
}
```

Next, delete your node_modules **and your yarn.lock**, then finally run `yarn install` again.